# Two tangent circles, find missing radius

Tags: circles

This is actually a CAD design I'm working on. Points $A$, $B$, and $C$ are fixed. Need $R_2$ when circles are externally tangent.

[image: diagram]

Comment: use Pythagoras Thm and calculate https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+%289.463%2B28.465%29%5E2%2B%28R%2B7.108%29%5E2%3D%2828.465%2BR%29%5E2 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vertical leg of the right triangle has length $9.463 + R_1 = 9.463 + 28.465 = 37.928$. The horizontal leg of the right triangle has length $7.108 + R_2$. The hypotenuese of the right triangle has length $R_1 + R_2 = 28.465 + R_2$. So, by the Pythagorean theorem, we have

$$37.928^2 + (7.108 + R_2)^2 = (28.465 + R_2)^2$$

which simplifies to (approximately)

$$678.801 - 42.714 R_2 = 0.$$

Thus, $$R_2 \approx 15.892.$$

Answer (score 2):

We have a right triangle with hypotenuse $R_1 + R_2$ and legs $R_1 + 9.463$ and $7.108 + R_2$. By the Pythagorean theorem,
$$
(R_1 + R_2)^2 = (R_1 + 9.463)^2 + (7.108 + R_2)^2.
$$
When you plug in $28.465$ for $R_1$, you are left with an equation in $R_2$ that an online calculator could solve.

Comment: In fact, the quadratic term is the same on both sides, so this is actually a linear equation!